# Entity framework in a multithread app: Object not set exception in Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: .net, multithreading, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an application that starts multiple threads in which a simple lookup is done in an Oracle database using entity framework 4.x. From time to time, I get an exception like this but I don't know why. Anyone came across such a situation and could help me?

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.SqlGen.SqlSelectStatement.WriteSql(SqlWriter writer, SqlGenerator sqlGenerator)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.SqlGen.SqlGenerator.WriteSql(ISqlFragment sqlStatement)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.EFOracleProviderServices.CreateCommand(EFOracleProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.EFOracleProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Span span, ReadOnlyCollection`1 compiledQueryParameters)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at ...
```

Fake code example to illustrate my situation:

```
public void Main()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
        {
            Task task = new Task(ThreadMethod);

            task.Start();

        }

    }

    private static void ThreadMethod()
    {
        var dbC = SmmsDBMgr.master_data_db;    // Here create DataContext


        var record = dbC.Products.
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.id)
                     .FirstOrDefault();   //Here I have the exception time to time.


        Console.WriteLine(record.id);
    }
```

Comment: what does GetList() do? if it can return null, .OrderByDescending will throw, otherwise FirstOrDefault() can return null, in which case record.id will throw.

Comment: I edited the code block, but it is really a simple access to a "Products" table and the exception is thrown upon FirstOrDefault() call. In my multithread app, this code block was called 55000 times and the exception popped up about 5 times.

Comment: It does not look like you are creating a new ObjectContext on each call!

Answer (score 3):

I have seen the same error.

I think this is a bug in Oracle.DataAccess.Client.

From decompiling the dll, I could see that the code in Oracle.DataAccess.Client.SqlGen.SqlSelectStatement.WriteSql(SqlWriter writer, SqlGenerator sqlGenerator) access a static field `Top_s`:

```
if (SqlSelectStatement.Top_s != null)
{
     writer.WriteLine();
     writer.Write("WHERE (");
     SqlSelectStatement.Top_s.WriteSql(writer, sqlGenerator);
     writer.Write(")");
     SqlSelectStatement.Top_s = null;
}
```

But as far as I can see, no syncronisation is used anywhere in the stack above. This seems to be the most obvious place where a NullReferenceException could occur when multiple threads execute this piece of code.

**Edit:**

I had created bug (25771235) with oracle and this issue is reported as fixed in Patch 26758841: WINDOWS DB BUNDLE PATCH 12.2.0.1.171017

Comment: I did find the bundle but I wasn't able to install it, it says no patch needed. Do you have an idea where we can find the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess that solve this issue

Comment: Hi have seen it in p26758841_122010_MSWIN-x86-64, path \files\odp.net\managed